# switch cursor focused between multiple monitor in osx

Tags: macos

anyone have any recommend osx app for me to use for switch cursor focused between multiple monitor by keyboard? I used `CatchMouse`. so after press keyboard, I can move cursor between  monitor but after upgrading osx to big sur it does not work anymore. For temp, I have to turn on Mouse keys to move the cursor https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-alternate-control-methods-preferences-mchl7b437b35/11.0/mac/11.0 however which is way more slow than just use app

Comment: I think you question is sent to wrong comunity. Ask in super user. (https://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with the same issue as I was a big Catchmouse fan and couldn't use it anymore after upgrading to big sure. I found another tool though called [Keymou](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/keymo/id449863619?mt=12) which also allows mapping keyboard shortcuts to switching screens and it works just like Catchmouse.